# Grails: Spring's @Transactional annotations are ignored sometimes

Tags: spring, grails, transactions

In the example below, I successfully fall into the end point - `mandatory()` - although one of two mutually exclusive `@Transactional` annotations must throw an exception: whether `Propagation.NEVER` or `Propagation.MANDATORY`. But the code is executed successfully.

How could that be?!

A couple (not all) of my services are affected by that and I'd like to understand what is the cause.

```
class NewService {

static transactional = true

boolean process() {
    return never()
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
boolean never() {
    return mandatory()
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
boolean mandatory() {
    // successfully breakpointed here o_O
    return true
}
}
```

Grails 2.2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are bypassing the bean proxy, as [Burt Beckwith](http://gr8conf.eu/Presentations/Grails-Transactions) (Slide 23) called it "Unintentionally bypassing the bean proxy".

You need to get proxy and execute your method on that.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
boolean never() {
    def myproxy= grailsApplication.mainContext.newService
    return myproxy.mandatory() 
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
boolean mandatory() {
    // successfully breakpointed here o_O
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring declarative transactions are AOP-based. And Spring AOP is proxy-based. This means that the transactional annotation is read and taken into account when a bean is called from **another** bean, through a proxy:

```
Bean A --> injected transactional proxy --> Bean B
```

In your case, you call another ethod of the same bean directly. The transactional proxy is thus not aware of this call, and thus can't enforce the presence of a transaction:

```
Bean A --> this
```